# How to Map IP type

Tags: rest, elasticsearch

this is my IPV4_DST_ADDR field mapping:

```
"IPV4_DST_ADDR":{"type":"text","norms":false,"fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}
```

I want to change the type from text to IP, how can I do?

thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to create a new field with the desired mapping(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ip.html), as there's no way to update an existing mapping.

Comment: but my everyday index is different such as "ntopng-2018.01.02" "ntopng-2018.01.03" etc. how can I mapping all the index thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read about `index templates`. Since, your indices follow some pattern, you can define your `index_patterns` like `ntopng-*` in your template file. 
Now, all your indices having this pattern will have this ip mapping on indexing.

For more info, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html

Comment: If I define the template, would all the related index change their type? such as yesterday indexed logstash-2018.01.05

Comment: this is my setting https://gist.github.com/Howard-Chang/808ed0f4c64c528051f284cee3ac0634, but the type I saw in kibana wasn't change. It is still "string"

Comment: No. This template will be applied only on the indices you have created after defining the template.

Comment: If you want previous indices to have type ip too, you can take a dump of already index data, delete those indices and recreate them with the backup data.